# How to know if a model or ActionExecutingContext argument is an entity (asp.net core 5)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core, .net-5

I'm starting a new project targeted `.net 5` using `ASP.NET Core 5`.

Sometimes in some `Actions` in some `Controllers` I need to check the received `model` if it is valid or not, so I created an `ActionFilter` class to use with any `Action` I want, all these actions will be `HttpPost` and will receive a `model`.
The problem is I tired from thinking about the best solution to know if the model is an entity or not from `OnActionExecuting` method, so I decided to make all my entities inherited from an `interface` named `IEntity` and in `OnActionExecuting` method check if a parameter is inherited from `IEntity` and check it's value as shown below.

**What I try :**

```
public class ValidationFilterAttribute : IActionFilter
    {
        public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
        {
            var param = context.ActionArguments.SingleOrDefault(p => p.Value is IEntity);
            if(param.Value == null)
            {
                context.Result = new BadRequestObjectResult("Object is null");
                return;
            }
            
            if(!context.ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                context.Result = new BadRequestObjectResult(context.ModelState);
            }
        }
        public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
        {          
        }
    }
```

**Question :**

Please is there any good method or technique to know if the `model` or one of the `context` `parameters` is an Entity without using Interface?

Comment: What do you mean by "entity"? You haven't tagged Entity Framework, so I'm guessing you're talking about something else?

Comment: sorry forgot it Imean by `Entity` entity framework `entity/class`

Comment: Since "entities" in EF are typically POCOs (with a few attributes maybe) there's nothing special about the types used as entities. Why does your controller actions use those entities instead of a DTO and why is it necessary for your filter to know that it's an entity?

Comment: What is the problem if I depend on entities directly instead of DTO ?

Comment: By following the principle of "Separation of concerns" you make it easier for yourself in the future to extend the functionality. By using a DTO, you can avoid that a simple change in the controller action also suddenly requires a database migration because you are using the same model for "frontend" and backend.

Answer (score 1):

Defining a marker interface for your entity types is not a bad idea. But it's not always applicable depending on your design. With the entity type itself, you cannot tell the difference from the normal types. But with the help of the `DbContext` containing the entity types, you can check if a type is an entity type by using the method `IModel.FindEntityType`

```
public class ValidationFilterAttribute : IActionFilter
{
    readonly YourDbContext _dbContext;
    public ValidationFilterAttribute(YourDbContext dbContext){
         _dbContext = dbContext;
    }
    public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        var hasAtLeastOneEntity = context.ActionArguments
                                         .Any(e => e.Value != null && 
                                                   _dbContext.Model.FindEntityType(e.Value.GetType()) != null);
        if(!hasAtLeastOneEntity)
        {
            context.Result = new BadRequestObjectResult("Object is null");
            return;
        }
        
        if(!context.ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            context.Result = new BadRequestObjectResult(context.ModelState);
        }
    }
    public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
    {          
    }
}
```

As in the code above, I assume that your `DbContext` type is `YourDbContext`, you can replace it with your actual `DbContext` type.

The performance should be good enough but in case you want it super fast (after performing some benchmarking and find it a bit slow), you can apply some caching strategy on the entity types. Although I'm not so sure if the default implementation of `IModel` itself should use some internal cache to manage the entity types.